# adding multiple files on page with file attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to have one single input type of file to add multiple files on page and found below code from: http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-file-element/

but i am pretty new to JavaScript and having issue to extend it, what I need is when it add file to page it should add a new input of type text where I can pass title for that file .

I tried this but its showing me a pop-up window when I add a new file element and input is not beside file.

http://jsfiddle.net/4JPzL/
Below an image example how I wants it to look like

[image: an image example how I wants it to look like]

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT FIX:**

Never mind i have fixed it here (cant answer my own question so here it goes...):

http://jsfiddle.net/4JPzL/2/

Regards

Comment: You can answer you own question and accept yourself. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/answering-your-own-question-immediately) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind i have fixed it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4JPzL/2/